# How to get only certain plots when plot() returns multiple plots

Tags: r

When I use plot() with a linear model, I get 4 plots, A normal QQ plot, residuals vs fitted, etc.

How do I get it so I only get the normal QQ plot, or only residual plot. I did it before, I think there is an argument like number= n or something. I need to know so I can save images for all the plots.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you should read the documentation of the function plot.lm which is the plot function dedicated to lm. You can select the graphs that you want to display with argument "which". There is 6 graphs that you can choose:

```
# for the qqplot & residual plot
plot(lm1, which=c(2,1))
```

hth

Comment: That is what makes R confusing for me... If I knew to type ?plot.lm, this question would be so easy. But I am using plot() to plot the data, so of course I am going to type ?plot which does not tell me about the "which" argument..

Comment: Yes it is not easy to find the appropriate function at the beginning. The fact is that R the class of the object is very important because it is an object-oriented programming language. For instance objects from lm function are of class "lm" (class(lm(...))). Once you know the class of your object you can search for the functions dedicated to this class: methods(class="lm"). You can see that there is a specific plot.lm function and then search for the details of this function. If there is no specific function then it is the default function that would be used for your object.